# How to write data in a specific tab of a spreadsheet with the Google Sheets API in Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm writing data in a Google Sheet using this function :

```
def Export_Data_To_Sheets(df):

response_date = service.spreadsheets.values().update(
    spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID_input,
    valueInputOption='RAW',
    range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,
    body=dict(
        majorDimension='ROWS',
        values=df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()[1:])
).execute()
print('Sheet successfully Updated')
```

It works well, but I have two tabs in my Google Sheet and I would like to choose in which one I want to write data. I don't know how can I do this.

Comment: Can you provide the value of `SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME` in your code? Usually you just have to make this value something like `"Sheet1!A1:D5"`.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you ! The value of SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME was "A2:A1000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this point in the code:

```
range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME
```

You can replace this value with a sheet and cell reference, something like:

```
range="Sheet1!A1:D5"
```

Reference

- [Writing a Single Range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing)